# Chess puzzles and gnuchess/xboard

Tags: engines

Just come back to chess after a long pause. I want to set up a position -- a simple one -- and then have gnuchess reply to my moves as I try for a mate. But, with a simple Q+K against K alone, gnuchess resigns after one move and I'd like it to play on. Can I persuade it to do this?

Comment: Use stockfish or another engine?

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the ResignScore option

[Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/chess/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options)

```
ResignScore
Default: 600

This is the score in centipawns that will trigger resign "counting".
```